# What can the average Astronomy Enthusiast do to learn more

Tags: planet, the-sun, solar-system, black-hole, galaxy

Maybe this sounds like a silly question (and hopefully is legitimate), but I will elaborate a little more.

I seem to love astronomy, every single thing about it, I find it brilliant, interesting, mysterious, insanely amazing and mind boggling.

There is only so many documentaries you can watch, read articles on the web etc before you start to see repetition.

I just wondered if there was some advice of what I could do to keep that interesting fire burning...because I absolutely love it!!

Comment: Read books? After all astronomy is a science. There are pretty neat ones for undergraduates summarizing large parts of astronomy, without being too mathy.

Comment: Join a [citizen science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_citizen_science_projects) project.

Comment: I suppose one of the best ways is to explore this site. We have plenty of information about a wide array of subjects.

Comment: Buy time on http://www.itelescope.net/ !!!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you learn your way around the night sky, so start by buying a book of star charts.  Next try a book that covers interesting objects in each constellation, such as Burnham's Celestial Handbook, or The Constellations by Motz & Nathanson.  This should keep you busy for a while.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a more serious course. Formal education is always an option if you have the time and money and there are many good MOOCs in astronomy. For example, [this Introduction to Astronomy](https://extend.duke.edu/courses/course-v1:DukeExtend+introastro+2016-2017/about) MOOC started today.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sip from the fire hose, try reading a few preprints via [arXiver](https://arxiver.wordpress.com/).
Some of those papers get published and some don't; some will interest you personally and some won't.
If something goes over your head at first, look it up, and if it still doesn't make sense, ask about it here.